# Ajax send data Json type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to submit Form ajax with **`jsontype`**

Let say I have 5 Field in that text box out of 5, 4 textbox normal Text one field value itself json so that ajax throw the error. How i can send

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**my.js**

```
function _getTest(){
                var data = JSON.stringify($("#formId").serialize());
               //alert(data); 
                $.ajax({
                url: "domain.com",
                datatype: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: data,              
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        alert(result.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
```

After Submit form i got status this **Status Code:400 Bad Request**

**General Tab**
Request URL:http://mycustomurl/com
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:35.154.113.130:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**Expected Payload**

```
{
    "name": "user",
    "mobile": "1234567890",
    "email": "my@gmail.com",
    "address": "test",
    "localityID": 1,
    "cityID": 1,
    "bookingDate": "2017-12-20",
    "timingID": "1",
    "paymentType": 1,
    "affiliateID": 15,
    "key": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "orderItems": [{
        "id": 3,
        "quantity": 2
           }, {
        "id": 4,
        "quantity": 5
    }]
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server's logs?

Comment: possible duplicates of:-[Getting 400 bad request error in Jquery Ajax POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16054639/4248328)

Comment: No this error i got in console HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Please check my question that;s different this is different

Comment: @Learning  that's why i din't duplicate your post, just added it as a comment

Comment: Can you send some prints and more info about request header, body, response etc? You can check it by clicking in the request name in network tab (chrome)

Comment: payload ::   "name=name&id=1&email=my%40gmil.com&mobile=1234567890&cityID=1&localityID=1&address=1&bookingDate=2017-12-31&timingID=1&orderItems=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2213%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2214%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D&affiliateID=1&key=1&password=1"

Comment: datatype: 'json', to data**T**ype: 'json',

Comment: Is the last field supposed to be a string (the JSON représentation of an array, or should it actually be th array directly? In the latter case, you need to `JSON.parse` the field’s value before stringifying the whole object.

Comment: @jcaron How to do that

Comment: @Roy Still same error only

Comment: @Learning serialize, replace orderItems with parsed version, then stringify the lot.

Comment: Can you please update answer

Comment: show us request (headers, payload) from console->network. What's your end-point?

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: @Learning can you please update your question by adding expected payload for hitting ajax, and also add payload generated by your code. As per my understanding it should be nested array,please update so that we can try to help you

Comment: @GSB Please check my updated question that's expected payload i want to send like that how i will send

Comment: @Learning ok, I understood structure of your payload. Can you please debug your code and check the generated payload by your code matches with the same structure?

Comment: This is my payload 
 
payload :: "name=name&id=1&email=my%40gmil.com&mobile=1234567890&cityID‌​=1&localityID=1&addr‌​ess=1&bookingDate=20‌​17-12-31&timingID=1&‌​orderItems=%5B%7B%22‌​id%22%3A%2212%22%2C%‌​22quantity%22%3A%221‌​%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22‌​%3A%2213%22%2C%22qua‌​ntity%22%3A%221%22%7‌​D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%2‌​214%22%2C%22quantity‌​%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D&‌​affiliateID=1&key=1&‌​password=1"

Comment: I don't know how to make that payload with mine

Comment: @Learning based on my understanding I have generated payload for you ,Please check my answer below.Hopefully it will help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160772/discussion-between-gsb-and-learning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding I have created below logic to create your payload. This code create exact structure you want to send as payload. In my code I have created mainData array to create payload. In your case you need to pass this mainData  as your ajax payload data. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```js
var mainData={};

$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#submit").click(function(){

    mainData='{'+'\n'+
    '"name":'+ $("#name").val()+',\n'+
    '"mobile": '+$("#mobile").val()+',\n'+
    '"email": '+$("#email").val()+',\n'+
    '"address": '+$("#address").val()+',\n'+
    '"localityID": '+$("#localityID").val()+',\n'+
    '"cityID": '+$("#cityID").val()+',\n'+
    '"bookingDate":'+$("#bookingDate").val()+',\n'+
    '"timingID": '+$("#timingID").val()+',\n'+
    '"paymentType":'+$("#paymentType").val()+',\n'+
    '"affiliateID": '+$("#affiliateID").val()+',\n'+
    '"key": '+$("#key").val()+',\n'+
    '"password":'+$("#password").val()+',\n'+
    '"orderItems": '+$("#orderItems").val()+'\n'+
   ' });';
   console.log("mainData=");
   console.log(mainData);



  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
<input type="number" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile"/>
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="address"/>
<input type="text" id="cityID" placeholder="City ID"/>
<input type="text" id="localityID" placeholder="Locality ID"/>
<input type="date" id="bookingDate" placeholder="Booking Date"/>
<input type="text" id="timingID" placeholder="Timing ID"/>
<input type="text" id="paymentType" placeholder="Payment Type"/>
<input type="text" id="affiliateID" placeholder="Affiliate ID"/>
<input type="text" id="key" placeholder="Key"/>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
<textarea type="text" id="orderItems" placeholder="order Items"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

After created payload from above code you can pass payload in your ajax as follows

```
function _getTest(){
                $.ajax({
                url: "domain.com",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(mainData),              
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        alert(result.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
```

I am also attaching output screenshot for the same
[image]

Comment: I got this error The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Comment: refer this link maybe it will help you to solve this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477344/the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect-in-spring-mvc-ajax]

Comment: and have you tried with `data: JSON.stringify(mainData)` in ajax call??

Comment: if i pass my console data directly to main data i got output dynamic not working